# Express4 returns error in a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I recive a "Express.js returns error in a POST request" when I try to send data in a POST resquest. How I can fix it?

My app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
var form = require('./routes/form')(app);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(7777, function(){
  console.log("Running...")
});
```

My form.js code:

```
module.exports = function(app){

  app.get('/form', function(req, res){
    res.render('form');
  });

  app.post('/send', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.name);
  });

};
```

My form.ejs code:

```
<form action="/send" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Console error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at /home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/routes/form.js:9:25
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at expressInit (/home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:33:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/victor/cam/CAMTalk/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: "returns error" — **What error?!**

Comment: what's printing in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont yet mounting your middlewares on app when you pass it to form. you first should mount your middle wares at least the `body-parser` one which is responsible for populating `req.body`. so move:

```
var form = require('./routes/form')(app);
```

after your body-parser middle ware and it should work.

In general **order matters**.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `value=""` from your input. I think you are setting always as empty this way.

Comment: Nonsense. It just explicitly sets the *default* value to an empty string. Even if `name` was an empty string, it wouldn't explain why `req.body` was undefined.